# Create six grid columns with a width of 1fr

Tags: css

my code is not working to set grid columns. However I'm following the exact same format as I've seen across the internet. Does someone know the solution to this? I think it might be by including a "repeat" function to create 6 grid columns of the same width. (it might work in VSC but it does not work in Cengage)


My grid-template-rows is working perfectly fine.

```
body {
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 640px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 30px 1fr 1fr 100px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you seen across the internet that you are replicating (provide links)? Also, share your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat;
```

should be

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.